# WMS get optimal size ratio upon defining bounding box

Tags: python, wms

I'm connecting with a WMS and saving a cropped map. Ideally I would like to just define the bounding box (`bbox`) and define either the height or width of the output image in pixels, to get the correct height/width ratio. However, I'm getting errors if I define the height or width. It's working when I define the size of the output image

```
from owslib.wms import WebMapService

url = 'https://rasterdata.hunzeenaas.nl/erdas-iws/ogc/wms/Rasterdata?service=WMS&request=getmap'
wms = WebMapService(url)

img = wms.getmap( layers='Luchtfoto_2015_Ortho_25cm_RGB_voorjaarsvlucht'],
                  styles=['default'],
                  srs='EPSG:3857',
                  bbox=(72865, 7022456, 730231, 7023717),
                  size=(1000,1000),
                  format='image/jpeg',
                  transparant=True )
out = open('output.jpg', 'wb')
out.write(img.read())
out.close()
```

How do I get the correct image size ratio, while defining the bounding box?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how generic this answer is, but it looks like the correct width/height ratio can be read from the bounding box of the WMS. Correcting the size of the output image with this ratio will lead to the desired result

Comment: Can you be more specific? How to read the aspect ratio from bounding box? E.g. can we assume that the horizontal and vertical values of bounding box use the same unit?

Answer (score 0):

Aspect ratio is Width/Height, so from the bounding box you get:

```
Height = NorthMax - NorthMin
Width = EastMax - EastMin
```

In your code the image size is 1000px by 1000px meaning a ratio of 1/1 meaning your width/height should be 1.